# Extend graceful shutdown time from 10 seconds to more than a minute

Tags: google-cloud-run

*I'm planning to move my application to google-cloud-run, and trying to understand what is doable and what parts of the applications needs to be redesigned. The application should be started when data is available, process all new data which becomes available while executing and then go to sleep.*

I have [seen some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71001475/how-do-graceful-shutdowns-work-when-max-instances-1) and  [a few answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64360972/391691) about graceful shutdown for a cloud run instance. My application would ideally need upto 90 seconds to make a graceful shutdown. Is it possible to change the 10 seconds from `SIGTERM` to `SIGKILL` to 90 seconds?

So the question is:

*Assuming we get the `SIGTERM` signal, which is not guaranteed*

***Is there a setting some where in Google control panels where the time between a `SIGTERM` and actual shutdown can be increased?***

Comment: Needless to say my experience with this cloud run is limited, feel free to point me to a duplicate question which I did not find ;-)

Comment: Cloud Run is not an operating system. Cloud Run applications respond to events such as Pub/Sub or HTTP requests and end when the response is returned. Review the [lifecycle](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/lifecycle-container-cloud-run) of a request. Take a look at [Cloud Run Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs) Your post does not have enough information to know which service would fit best. If you have a traditional application design, Compute Engine is a good choice even for containers.

Comment: @JohnHanley yes I know that, my application will trigger on pubsub events but I didn't think that was important for my question. The application is currently running on Compute Engine but that information is also not needed for the minimal reproducible example. If there was any wording above which is not clear or misused in this context please let me know so we can improve the question.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks, but the question is not about which service is the best fit, it is about if extending the 10 second shutdown time is possible or not.

Comment: The idle state is probably what I'm looking for in the second part of the question.

Comment: Read some of my comments in the Q&A that you reference. With Cloud Run there is no shutdown time that you control and your container can be killed at any time. Your app returns a response and is done. Think of it as an HTTP request and response with a web server. You can enable always-on CPU so that there can be background processing at an increased cost. Also, keep in mind that your app should be stateless as requests can arrive at a different instance.

Comment: There was one close vote asking for clarification, which makes no sense to me, so I guess the answer is No there is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No it is not possible**

All entries in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-execution-environments) only reefer to this grace time only as *10 seconds* there are never any indications it could be reconfigured