# GCP Cloud Run container stalls when using Cloud Build to deploy with tag "latest" and same image name

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

I have spent the last few days investigating this issue and tried many things. The issue started around February 7th, 2024.

The summary of the issue is:

- When I deploy a replacement service to GCP Cloud Run using Cloud Build and container registry, my container stalls and is forcibly `SIGTERM`'ed by Cloud Run for exceeding maximum request timeout.
- I was able to pinpoint the point of the stall in my container to a function that
  uses the GCP Spanner python package, so I believe it may be authentication related.
- When using GCP console and reverting to the previous working revision, the container worked as expected.
- On a hunch I deployed the same container to a different service name + image name with tag "latest" in container registry, which worked. Container did not time out and all GCP APIs worked as expected.
- In the same vein, I tried redeploying to the new service name using a different image name with the tag "latest", which worked as well.

The format of my Cloud Build .yaml file is:

```
steps:
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'docker build --build-arg=GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN=$$_GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN -t gcr.io/myproject/containername:latest .']
  secretEnv: ['_GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN']
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/myproject/containername:latest']
 - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: gcloud
  args: ['run', 'deploy', 'container name', '--image', 'gcr.io/myproject/containername:latest', '--region', 'us-central1']
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
 - versionName: projects/myproject/secrets/git_access_token_my_repo/versions/latest
    env: '_GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN'
images:
 - 'gcr.io/myproject/containername:latest'
```

Our team has been using this exact format for over a year with no issues. Whenever we deploy a service we would run this `gcloud` command and wouldn't make any changes to the .yaml file:

```
gcloud builds submit --region=us-central1 --config cloudbuild.yaml
```

However that no longer works, and when we deploy the service now we modify the .yaml file like this (different image name):

```
steps:
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'docker build --build-arg=GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN=$$_GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN -t gcr.io/myproject/containernamev2:latest .']
  secretEnv: ['_GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN']
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/myproject/containernamev2:latest']
 - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: gcloud
  args: ['run', 'deploy', 'container name', '--image', 'gcr.io/myproject/containernamev2:latest', '--region', 'us-central1']
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
 - versionName: projects/myproject/secrets/git_access_token_my_repo/versions/latest
    env: '_GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN'
images:
 - 'gcr.io/myproject/containernamev2:latest'
```

My questions are:

- Why doesn't the old .yaml file work anymore? Does it have something to with the deprecation of container registry?
- If it's permissions related how can I check this?
- Was there some change that happened around February 7th?

---

Dockerfile for additional context:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
ARG GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install gcc -y \
&& apt-get clean \
&& apt-get install -y git

RUN git config --global url."https://${GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir git+ssh://git@github.com/myorg/my-repo.git@main#subdirectory=python_packages/src/package-one
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir git+ssh://git@github.com/myorg/my-repo.git@main#subdirectory=python_packages/src/package-two

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

Comment: what does your flask look like?

Comment: @randomdatascientist Can you provide the logs, Detailed logs might give insights into what's causing the issue

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/samples/cloudrun-sigterm-handler)  Cloud Run sends a SIGTERM signal to your container instance before the container instance terminates, due to an event like scale down or deleted revision. By handling this signal, you can now gracefully terminate your applications and do some cleanup tasks–as opposed to an abrupt shutdown of the container.

Comment: @SathiAiswarya there is nothing in the logs. It simply get's to the point where it is attempting to make a SQL query on Google Spanner using the spanner python client and doesn't progress - just hangs - then times out. When it was working before (and when it works with the modifications to the .yaml file above) it only takes ~8 seconds. The maximum request timeout for the service is 300 seconds (5 minutes).

Comment: Have a look at this [link](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/How-does-Cloud-Run-end-a-request-on-timeout/m-p/596676) & this stackoverflow [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71002676/18265638),[thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491005/handling-a-cloud-run-container-shutdown)

Comment: @randomdatascientist Have you managed to check the above comment,does that help? if not can you provide reproducible steps or document that you are following